# How can I retrieve HTTP responses from recorded log without receiving actual response from the server?

Tags: html, httprequest, httpresponse, fiddler, session-replay

**I think this is how should it work:** I record the HTTP activity while browsing my website online. Then, When running my website's HTML offline, no network activity is made. And when a request is made, a response is retrieved from the recorded log.

I need to know how can I make this.

I think [this tool](http://documentup.com/assaf/node-replay) is little near from what I want to do. But, unfortunately I don't know how to use it for my case.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you tagged this post with `Fiddler` suggests that you know that Fiddler can already do this using the `AutoResponder` tab. You may wish to update your question to explain why you don't want to do that.